# Powershell - issue with users created in AAD via Powershell to allocate to a distribution list

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I'm trying to automate the full user creation in Azure AD / Office 365 using Powershell.
I succeded to create the user, allocate the licence but I'm failing at allocating the user to an existing Office 365 distribution list.

I'm using the following code :

1. to create the user

   ```
   $DisplayName = "DOE John"
   $GivenName = "John"
   $SurName = "Doe"
   $JobTitle = "Tester"
   $Country = "FR"
   $Office = "MyCie"
   $UPN = "j.doe@mycie.fr"
   $UsageLocation = "FR"
   $MailNickName = "Jonny"
   $Password = "TempPwd_202112"
   $PasswordProfile=New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
   $PasswordProfile.Password = $Password


   New-AzureADUser -DisplayName $DisplayName -GivenName $GivenName -SurName $SurName -JobTitle     $JobTitle -Country $Country -PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName $Office -UserPrincipalName $UPN -UsageLocation $UsageLocation -MailNickName $MailNickName  -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile -AccountEnabled $true -ShowInAddressList $true
   ```

--> when executing this cmd, the new user is actually created/displayed in the active directory
--> when looking at the characteristics, I can not see any difference with a user created manually

Beware that once added, I'm still forced to run following to have the user displayed in the AD:

```
Set-Mailbox -Identity j.doe@quito.aero -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
Set-Mailbox -Identity j.doe@quito.aero -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $false
```

Once done, he is available in the Group Address List

2. to add the user to the General Cie distribution list called "All MyCie users"

   ```
   $UPN = "j.doe@mycie.fr"
   Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity  "All MyCie users" -Member $UPN
   ```

--> executing this cmd results in no error but the user never shows in the distribution list in Office 365 portal or in Outlook when expending the list. If executed again, the command fails indicating that the user already belongs to the distribution list.

--> if I connect to the Office portal and to the distribution list members, the user does show in the users that can be added but when trying to add, it results in an error "Error managing members for 1 user(s) : DOE John.

My assumption is that I'm missing a setting when creating the user in Azure Active Directory that prevents me from adding him in the distribution list but I can't figure out which one or if I'm doing something wrong. I compared the user settings with manually created profile but can't figure out any obvious difference.

--> if I run the cmd with a user created manually, it works fine.

Do you have any idea or suggestion ?

Regards

Frederic

Comment: Is this a typo? `-    UsageLocation $UsageLocation` (the spaces between the dash and the parametername should not be there) and is your `$PasswordProfile` indeed a valid `Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile` ?

Comment: Hi Theo, there was indeed a typo that I've just corrected.
Besides, I added the lines to make the password profile working.
Nevertheless, I'm still experiencing the same issue once the user is created.

Comment: Can you try creating the Azure AD User with the mail address

Comment: Sorry RamaraoAdapa but I'm not sure to understand what you mean.
When I create the user, the UPN is indeed the mail address !
Could you clarify what you suggest to try, please ?

Comment: I tried the same way to create the user. But I get mail address empty. So  while creating the user, you can add Mail so that the user will be created with a mail address. Mail address and UPN are different

Comment: Thank you RamaraoAdapa for this suggestion but I can't find any option in the cmd "New-AzureADUser" to add mail. There are only mentions of -MailNickname or -OtherMails but neither of them seem correct in my case. In fact the user's email address and UPN should be both j.doe@mycie.fr in my case even though these are different fields or options.
Could you point me to the direction on how you suggest to create the user with the mail address, please ?

Comment: Remark : once the user is created, you have to allocate a licence (Exchange) for the mail to be indeed activated. But even with this additional step (allocating a licence), the user created in Powershell can't be added to a distribution list.

Comment: I also tried to create Azure AD user with mail. But unable to create. For the workaround, you can add the mail in the portal and then try to add the user to distribution list

Comment: You can also create user with New-AzADUser instead of New-AzureADUser. Then you can create user with mail

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

When we create the user with PowerShell using **New-AzureADUser** command, the user is created without the Mail Address.

[image]

We need to add the Email of the user either manually or using **New-AZADUser** command.

Then you would be able to add the user to the Distribution List

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found what was wrong.
In fact the script is working just fine. The user was created and corretcly added to the distribution list with my original syntax.
It seems that there is a bug in the web browser interface of Office 365 (office.com portal) when dealing with distribution list with more than approximately 1500 users. In such lists, even though the users are correctly added, they don't show up.
So this is not a script problem but a GUI bug in the web portal.
Thanks for your help and support